# How to change the language in multiple pages at once?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown button which offers two languages, my native and English. The thing is, when I change it in English, it changes the text on that page, but the rest of the pages are still in my native. The script is connected with all of them. Is there something that I missed to do?
Here is the code for the dropdown:

```
     <div class="dropdown pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle btn-lg" id="menu1" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Јазик / Language
                <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                <li role="presentation" value="1"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Македонски</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" value="2"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">English</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

And here is how I change the text in the script. These are from two two pages in this site:

```
       $("ul li").on('click', function () {
    var val = $(this).val();

    if(val==2){
        $("#buy").html("Buy ticket");
        $("#validate").html("Validate ticket");
        $("#q1").html("How many tickets would you like to buy?");
        $("#back").html("Back");
        $("#q2").html("Please enter" + "<span class='den'></span>" + "denars in the slot labeled as 'ENTER'");
        $("#q3").html("Please take your ticket/s and your change!");
        $("#q4").html("Thank you");
        $("#q5").html("Please show the barcode on your ticket in front of the camera.");
        $("#q6").html("Successful validation! Thank you!");
    }else{
        $("#buy").html("Купи карта");
        $("#validate").html("Валидирај карта");
        $("#q1").html("Колку карти сакате да купите?");
        $("#back").html("Назад");
        $("#q2").html("Ве молиме внесете вредност од" + "<span class='den'></span>" + "денари во слотот назначен со „ВНЕСИ“.");
        $("#q3").html("Ве молиме подигнете ја/ги картата/те и кусурот.");
        $("#q4").html("Ви благодариме!");
        $("#q5").html("Ве молиме покажете го баркодот од картата пред камерата");
        $("#q6").html("Успешна валидација! Ви благодариме!");
    }
});
```

Comment: use a cookie or localStorage to keep track of current language and also adjust on page load if applicable ... not just using click handler

Comment: why you didnt add sth in url for tracking language for other pages?
for example when user set english, url changes to example.com/en and you can find out request is for which language and response correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you navigate from one page to another, none of the state of the first page, or any of its JavaScript state, is passed to the second page; the second page loads from scratch as if the first page had never existed.

I assume in your pages the navigation menu is the same across all your pages, but even though it may be identical across pages, what's happening when you go from page A to page B is that the entire page, including the common navigation stuff is getting loaded and rendered from scratch, in its initial, pre-on-click state.

There are multiple techniques that you can use to pass an bit of state from one page to the next. For this scenario, the easiest is probably a cookie.

[JavaScript cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

[jquery cookie plugin](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/)

What you would do is set a cookie like lang=1 or lang=2 whenever the language is changed. Make your language switching code a separate function that can be called from on-click, but also on page load (or page ready). On page load/ready, if the lang cookie is present, call your language switching function with the value of the lang cookie.  All your pages would have the same code for click and for page load/ready.

[jquery .ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Thank you so much. If you can help me with only one thing more I will be really grateful. I fixed this with cookies like you suggested, but I want to know how to make a default state, that will show each time the page is opened. Right now, when I refresh the page, the home page is in its initial state, like it should, but when I open the other pages they are still under the influence of the cookie. I tried with expiration, but it only works on the first page. I hope you understood what my problem is.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed this by making another cookie that checks if the page is in the final state, and if it is it restores the first values.